# Send html form in php with smtp

Tags: php, html, forms, email, smtp

Update: My send.php now looks like this and when i click send got a blank page and send nothing. I have the class.phpmailer.php in the right place.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHPMailer - SMTP basic test with authentication</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

error_reporting(E_STRICT);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();



$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.******.hu"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.******.hu"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "support@******.hu"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "******";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('support@******.hu', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("support@******.hu","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$address = "support@******.hu";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "support@******.hu");

  $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $call = $_POST['call'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $priority = $_POST['priority'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $address = "support@******.hu";

    $formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
    $formcontent= eregi_replace("[\]",'',$formcontent);
    $mail->MsgHTML($formcontent);


if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Helo!
I want to send a html form in email with this php code but not working...
I don't know why... If you know the solution please help me :)
Thank you!

The HTML form:

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform">

<form id="form1" action="send.php" method="POST">

    <label>Név
        <span class="small">Kérem adja meg nevét</span>
    </label>
<input type="text" name="name">
    <label>Email
        <span class="small">Kérem valós címet adjon meg</span>
    </label>
<input type="text" name="email">


<br />
<br />

    <label>Telefon
        <span class="small">Visszahíváshoz adja meg telefonszámát</span>
    </label>
<input type="text" name="phone">

<br />
<br />

    <label>Elérhetőség
        <span class="small">Kérem adja meg mikor érhetjük el telefonon</span>
    </label>

<select name="priority" size="1">
<option value="Low">Délelőtt</option>
<option value="Normal">Délután</option>
<option value="High">Este</option>
<option value="Emergency">Egész nap</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<br />
    <label>Szolgáltatás
        <span class="small">Mivel kapcsolatban keres minket?</span>
    </label>
<select name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Szolgáltatás Megrendelése</option>
<option value="change">Szolgáltatás Lemondás</option>
<option value="addition">Információ</option>
<option value="new">Hiba Bejelentése</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<br />

  <label>Tárgy
        <span class="small">Írja le az üzenet tárgyát</span>
    </label>
 <input type="text" name="website">

<br />
<br />
<br /> 

    <label>Üzenet
        <span class="small">Írja le üzenetét</span>
    </label>
<textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="29"></textarea><br />

    <button type="submit" value="Send" style="margin-top:15px;">Küldés</button>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</form>

</div>
```

And my php:

```
<?php

    //error_reporting(E_ALL);
    error_reporting(E_STRICT);



    $mail             = new PHPMailer();


    $formcontent             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$formcontent);

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "mail.myserver.hu"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                               // 1 = errors and messages
                                               // 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = "mail.myserver.hu"; // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "support@myserver.hu"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "myserverpass";        // SMTP account password

    $mail->SetFrom('email@myserver.hu', 'First Last');

    $mail->AddReplyTo("email@myserver.hu","First Last");

    $mail->Subject    = "test";

    $mail->AltBody    = "test"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail->MsgHTML($formcontent);

    $formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $call = $_POST['call'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $priority = $_POST['priority'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $address = "email@myserver.hu";



    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
    }

    ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Please help me if you can! :) Thaks!

Comment: Check the end of your PHP code. It has `</body>` and `</html>`. Also put the PHP code in the `send.php` file and save it in same folder you have the HTML file. If you face any error, then post it.

Comment: I got server error 500 but my .htaccess file is ok.. I tested the php mailer with the basic and its work. But my code don't work

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add `$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";`

Answer (score 0):

You just made one mistake you need to put all variables before use them, like this :

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $call = $_POST['call'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $priority = $_POST['priority'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $address = "email@myserver.hu";

    $formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
    $formcontent= eregi_replace("[\]",'',$formcontent);
    $mail->MsgHTML($formcontent);
```

Comment: add php mailer class like : require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

Comment: added and copy the class.phpmailer.php to the right place and got server 500error again :(

Comment: Ok. I add <html><head></head></body></html> to the send.php and i got the "You must provide at least one recipient email address. Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address."

Comment: Sorry a forgot to write here but i added there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mail basic function PHP... with this short code:

```
Class Mailer{

        public static function sendMailNewUser($username,$firstname,$lastname,$password){

            $to = $username;
            $from_name = "INFO MAIL";
            $from_mail = "noreply@mail.it";
            $subject = "New User";

            $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

            // header
            $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
            $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
            $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8\r\n";
            $message = "Welcome $firstname $lastname, ";
            $message .= "<br><br>";
            $message .= "This is your account:<br>
                         <b>username: $to<br>
                         password: $password</b><br>";


            mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);


        }

}
```

Comment: Can't use this because my hosting don't enable the mail function.

Comment: Ah sorry... with my hosting this is my solution